# How to block torrents on dlink 605L router?

Tags: networking, router

I want to block torrents on my dlink 605L router. I read about it and found that blocking torrents is very difficult, so I came to the conclusion that blocking all ports except web, mail, and ftp ports should do the trick.

Could someone explain how I can do this on this router?

I could not find any QoS options on it.

This is what the router page looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr0ng.png]

Comment: If you allow Port 80, the first thing torrent will try is port 80 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this with firewall, not QoS.

That is, if the firewall settings are capable of doing it on this router.  I actually don't think you can achieve this with your router.

Log into your router, go the firewall settings page:

- `<login>`
- Click on **Manual Setup** button
- Click on **Advanced** (on the top)
- Click on **firewall and DMZ** button (on the left)

Create a block/deny rule for everything, from IP 1.1.1.1 to 254.254.254.254, you may need to put in ports, 0-65000.  (you will need to lookup the actual high end port number, but that should cover you to start with).

Then create allow rules for the same IP range 1.1.1.1 to 254.254.254.254 for each of the service port destinations that you want to enable, port 25 to smtp, port 80 for https, port 443 for https, etc.

**If this does not work, then you can not achieve what you want to do with with your router.**

You could achieve what you want to do with an old computer repurposed as a Firewall/Router.  IPCop, SmoothWall, M0n0wall, and pfSense all come to mind immediately.  Or you could buy a Cisco or Juniper device.

QoS is for `Quality of Service` which has to do with traffic prioritisation.

ref:  dlink 605L emulator http://support.dlink.com/Emulators/dir605L/111/index.html